# PowerQuery Replace Text Values Multiple If statement

Tags: replace, powerquery, nested-if

Using PowerQuery I have a column with long RAG descriptions eg "No Significant Issues [Green]" which I want to replace with R, A or G based on the text or leaves as is if not match found.

The following code works for Green but is not replacing the Amber statement. I have copied the text exactly.

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Reordered Columns",each[RAGQuality],each if [RAGQuality]="No Significant Issues [Green]" then "G" else each if [RAGQuality]="Significant Issues [Amber]" then "A" else [RAGQuality], Replacer.ReplaceText,{"RAGQuality"})
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `else each if` might need to be `else if`. Try:

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Reordered Columns", each [RAGQuality], each if [RAGQuality] = "No Significant Issues [Green]" then "G" else if [RAGQuality] = "Significant Issues [Amber]" then "A" else [RAGQuality], Replacer.ReplaceText, {"RAGQuality"})
```

- I think your code is making a case-sensitive comparison (and therefore won't, for example, replace `"No significant issues [Green]"` with `"G"`). This might be exactly what you want, but I mention it in case it's not. `Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` can be used to make case-insensitive comparisons.
- There doesn't seem to be an `else if` clause for `R`/`[Red]` in the code, but maybe you haven't gotten that far yet.
- You might want to look at `Record.FieldOrDefault` which can reduce the number of `if` checks you're making (or creating some sort of `record` or `list` of the replacements you need to make, and then just loop over it).

Comment: Thanks chillin  - I have had a rethink on approach - finding the key word in the various texts eg [Green] is better than finding/replacing the whole text and avoids any mispelling/Capitalisation issues. Repeating the code for the other 4 RAG fields now works fine. I'll have a look at your other suggestion re Record.FieldOrDefault.

Answer (score 0):

This has done the trick:

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Reordered Columns",each[RAGQuality],each if Text.Contains([RAGQuality], "[Red]") then "n" else if Text.Contains([RAGQuality], "[Amber]") then "u" else if Text.Contains([RAGQuality], "[Green]") then "l" else [RAGQuality], Replacer.ReplaceText,{"RAGQuality"})
```

And is a neater solution than looking for each text to replace as now easy to edit column names for other 5 columns which all have [Red] or [Amber] or [Green] as the key text but differing remaining text